# Play Integrety API xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I develop in xamarin.Forms.

I'm trying to use the Play Integrety API to check if an .apk or device is genuine.
I don't know how to go about doing this check.

From my research I found a package Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Integrety but I see no documentation on how to use it.

thank you for helping me